# CreateThread passing std::string as argument

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, clr

I need to create a thread in a managed C++ code (CLR) to call an unmanaged C++ class member function passing a `std::string` as a parameter. The thread is being called, but the received `std::string` is being received as an empty string:

**The managed code:**

```
std::string param;
CreateThread(0, NULL, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE) &MyThread.Start, &MyThread, (DWORD) &param, NULL);
```

**The unmanaged code:**

```
class MyThread
{
    public:
        MyThread();
        static void Start(std::string &param);
};

void MyThread::Start(std::string &param)
{
    std::cout << param << std::endl; <<=== param is empty here
}
```

Comment: There's a couple of things that are causing this issue, but it's not clear if you are keeping the `std::string param` variable around during the life time of the thread? Also, you're passing it as the [`dwCreationFlags`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682453%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) parameter.

Comment: Indeed the parameter was placed in the wrong position. I suggest you put it as a definitive answer. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specifically in your case, you're passing `&MyThread` as the thread function parameter and passing the `param` as the `dwCreationFlags` parameter of the [`CreateThread`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682453%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function, which specifies thread creation options.

Additionally, you'll need to make sure you keep `param` around for the lifetime of the thread.

Hope that helps.

Comment: That´s it. Solved.